# Include header files in a built shared library

Tags: qt

I'm using Qt Creator 3.5.1 (opensource) with Qt 5.5.1. There I've created a shared library, and I can successfully build it. In the resulting build folder I find the so-file as expected, but I can't find the header files which are needed to use the library. Are the header files not expected to turn up here? I though the build folder would contain everything needed in order to make use of the library. Is that not the case?

Comment: header files don’t move anywhere during a normal build (and shouldn’t). If you want to install them, you need to create install rules so they get installed via `make install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they should be placed there. That is the build directory, not the installation directory. You can however also define the installation behaviour; see [Advanced Usage - Installing Files](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#installing-files). You choose which headers to distribute and which are private and place the public ones in the proper position.